# rails 3.2.1 can not show flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue by showing the flash :notice in rails 3.2.1. Here my code

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :user_can_upload, :only => [:new, :add_image]
  #...actions
  def new
    @asset = Asset.new
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # new.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @asset }
   end
  end

  private
  def user_can_upload
     if current_user.can_upload?
       redirect_to dashboard_index_path, notice: I18n.t(:quota_assets)
     end
  end
end
```

in my main layout i have

```
%body
= render 'layouts/shared/header'
-if notice
  .container
    .alert.alert-success=raw notice
= yield
```

for example, in new action redirect works fine but no notice message are shown.
Any hint?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to output the flash message, you have to use `flash[:notice]` not `notice`.